# Finding Range Method

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

It's about the equation in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCtCX.png).

I want to find the range of the function, but I don't know how. The shown solution is way to complicated for me, so if anyone could explain or show a easiert method, that would be much appreciated.

I know that $x^2-x+1$ can't be zero for all $x$ and that therefore the domain is not limited

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution given isn’t actually all that complicated once you realize what is being done.

If $t$ is in the range of $f$, there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$t=\frac{x^2}{x^2-x+1}\,.\tag{1}$$

The idea is to try to solve for $x$ in terms of $t$: if we can find a real number $x$ making $(1)$ true, then we know that $t$ really is in the range of $f$, and if we can show that such a real number does not exist, then we know that $t$ is not in the range of $f$.

We know that $x^2-x+1>0$, so we can multiply both sides by $x^2-x+1$ to get $t(x^2-x+1)=x^2$, or $tx^2-tx+t=x^2$. Subtracting $x^2$ from both sides, we get $(t-1)x^2-tx+t=0$.

If $t=1$, this is simply $-x+1=0$, or $x=1$. This shows that $1$ is in the range of $f$: specifically, $1=f(1)$.

If $t\ne 1$, this is a quadratic in $x$, so we apply the quadratic formula to find that

$$x=\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-4t(t-1)}}{2(t-1)}\,.$$

This is a real number if and only if $t^2-4t(t-1)\ge 0$, which we can rewrite as $-3t^2+4t\ge 0$ and then as $t(-3t+4)\ge 0$. It’s convenient to divide both sides by $-3$; since we’re dividing by a negative number, the direction of the inequality is reversed, and we find that $x$ is a real number if and only if

$$t\left(t-\frac43\right)\le 0\,.$$

A product of two numbers is negative if and only if one number is negative and the other is positive. Clearly $t-\frac43<t$, so in this case that happens precisely when $t-\frac43<0<t$. And the product is $0$ if and only if at least one of the numbers is $0$, so $x$ is a real number if and only if $t-\frac43\le 0\le t$. Finally, $t-\frac43\le 0$ if and only if $t\le\frac43$, so $x$ is a real number if and only if $0\le t\le\frac43$.